# android studio 3.0.1 emulator not working

Tags: android, android-studio

I am just new to android studio and I tried to emulate app for the first time. When I click on run button and the emulator opens with an error " Cold boot: snapshot doesn't exist ".
 
 Please tell me the steps solve to this problem

Answer (score 0):

Quick Boot is not reliable when software rendering is enabled. If Quick Boot does not work, click Edit this AVD from the AVD Manager and change Graphics from either Automatic or Software to Hardware.

Source: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator.html#quickboot-troubleshooting